# Como el elimino dato en concreto

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy trabajando con una api quiero borrar un elemento elemento en concreto estoy trabando con:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com .

He probado con el método.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', {
  method: 'DELETE',
});
```

Pero quiero eliminar un álbum en concreto con el nombre.

Comment: Eso lo tenes que manejar desde el backend, no el front

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Para eso debes saber el título, y suponiendo que lo sabes, debes hacer primero otro fetch de los albums para poder recorrerlos y localizar su id correspondiente mediante un condicional, y cuando sepas su id finalmente podras eliminarlo con esto:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/' + id, {
  method: 'DELETE',
});
```

donde `id` representa el **id** que has conseguido con los pasos previos.

Encontrarás todo lo que necesitas en la web que tu mismo has señalado en la pregunta: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/